# Undefined reference to memrchr in GCC

Tags: c, gcc, gnu

I am trying to use `memrchr` in my project. It is a [GNU extension function](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Search-Functions.html). But I am getting `undefined reference to 'memrchr'` error. I have included `string.h`. `__GNUC__` is defined and has a value of 12. My GCC version is 12.2.0.

```
> gcc --version
gcc.exe (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.2.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Minimal reproducible example:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <string.h>

int main() {
    memrchr("hello", 'l', 5);
}
```

```
> gcc .\src\temp.c
.\src\temp.c: In function 'main':
.\src\temp.c:6:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'memrchr'; did you mean 'memchr'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    6 |         memrchr("hello", 'l', 5);
      |         ^~~~~~~
      |         memchr
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SOURAV~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccodiFYq.o:temp.c:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `memrchr'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Can you provide a short [mcve] and the command line you use to compile it?

Comment: Here's an example that should work. https://godbolt.org/z/zKqqhdfKj You need to define `_GNU_SOURCE` before any standard library includes. You can do that on the command line as I have or in your code as the commented out line shows. Command line is generally better since you don't have to define it in a bunch of different places.

Comment: Ensure that you aren't compiling as standard C (for example `-std=c17` or `-pedantic`) or otherwise gcc will strip all non-standard stuff from the standard headers.

Comment: Also you can use standard C `strrchr` for the same purpose, it will just be slightly slower and you need a zero at the end of the data.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I tried defining `_GNU_SOURCE`. Still not working. I have added minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Lundin No, I'm not using compiling as standard C.